# Is the ckeditor or other editor supposed to be automatically installed?

Tags: wysiwyg

In a fresh install of Drupal 7, when you create and article or page, is there supposed to be an editor?  When I create an article or page, it's just the text area where you type in the content.  There is no editor so I can bold, upload an image, justify, etc.

Did I do something wrong?

admin/config/text formats, Full html, Administrator; I am the administrator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there's no WYSIWYG editor included with Drupal, you need to install one of the contrib modules.

[WYSIWYG](https://drupal.org/project/WYSIWYG) is the standard solution as it gives you a choice of editors, but there are others like the standalone [CKEditor](https://drupal.org/project/ckeditor) module.

Answer (score 1):

you can also install WYSIWYG and from :

Configuration > Wysiwyg profiles

see a list of editors (ckeditor,TinyMCE, ...)  that you can install. there is also download link as well, simply download and extract them.

now create a folder in sites/all and rename it to libraries and copy the extracted folder there.

the .js files which are described in the list must be in your editor folder in the right place